# Connected components or inverse search with the Boost Graph Library

Tags: c++, boost-graph, boost-property-map

Is it possible to run `connected_components()` against a bidirectional graph (constructed with `::boost::bidirectionalS`) in the BGL? I get a segmentation violation when running something like this with a graph constructed that way:

```
int num_comp = connected_components(g,
    make_iterator_property_map(component.begin(), get(vertex_index, g)));
```

This isn't surprising, since the documentation indicates that it's only usable against undirected graph.

Failing that, is it possible to use one of the search algorithms (BFS or DFS) in the *inverse* direction? For example, I'd like to start my search at a terminal vertex (one with no outbound edges) and work backward.

I might be asking the wrong question, too: what I'm trying to do is find the subgraph of all vertices with a path to a given terminal vertex. Is there a more direct way to do that with the BGL?

I can do all that myself, of course, but I'd prefer to use BGL facilities if I can.

Comment: I'd either write it on my own or try out http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/dfs_visitor.html

Comment: Have at look at [boost::make_reverse_graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/reverse_graph.html). It will switch the direction of your directed edges.